# Anaconda Python: How to install missing dependency?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install `graph-tool` from here: http://anaconda.org/vgauthier/graph-tool, using the command mentioned on that page.

I used the given command line:

```
conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier graph-tool
```

and I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find some dependencies for graph-tool: pixman

So I tried to install `pixman` in a similar way: http://anaconda.org/rwest/pixman.

```
conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/rwest pixman
```

This succeeded.

Yet the "could not find dependency" error is still there when trying to install `graph-tool`.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it?  There is no additional error message that I could go on.

Comment: Have you used conda install?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque As I mentioned in the question, I used the precise command shown in the linked pages.  E.g., `conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier graph-tool`.

Comment: ok - maybe you could try --> conda update conda --> conda update anaconda --> conda update graph-tool and see if that helps? (these are 3 distinct commands). Did the error message give a list of the dependencies to install?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque conda and anaconda are already at their latest versions (but I ran the conda update commands anyway).  `conda update graph-tool` fails because `graph-tool` is not installed.  The only error displayed when trying to install graph-tool is what I mentioned inthe post ([complete text](http://pastebin.com/PiMP57Ex)). `conda list pixman` shows that pixman is already installed. Is it maybe a version mismatch?  Can I explicitly ask it to list graph-tool dependencies with versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conda needs to be able to find all the dependencies at once. The `-c` flag only adds that channel for that one command. You would need to run `conda install -c vgauthier rwest graph-tool`. But an easier way is to add those channels to your configuration

```
conda config --add channels vgauthier --add channels rwest
```

Once you do this, you can just run

```
conda install graph-tool
```

and it will grab things from those channels.

Comment: But if you use `vi .condarc` you can find that even if by separately adding channels, `conda` can find them all,

Answer (score 0):

## Conflicting dependencies for `Anacona 2020.11`

When setting up a [`fedora-33` virtual machine](https://www.qubes-os.org/news/2021/02/25/fedora-33-templates-available/) with Anaconda (Version 2020.11) in April 2021, I got conflicting dependencies, as `graph-tool` was not compatible with `python version 3.8.5`. An pointed out [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2447), the way to go is using a virtual environment with a supported version of python (3.7.9. in my case, as I still new from Anaconda version 2020.03).

In my case it was important to install Anaconda **NOT** as `sudo`.
Otherwise some `conda`-**alias** was not set properly (`which conda` should give an about 30 lines command with some if/else condition).

Here are the bash commands:

```sh
$ cd ~/Downloads/
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ sudo chown -R user:user /opt/  # needed in my case to avoid sudo for installing Anaconda and calling conda later
$ bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh  # location: /opt/anaconda3, run conda init: yes
$ source ~/.bashrc  # make command conda available. Like restarting terminal in this case.
$ conda create -n envGraphTool anaconda python=3.7.9
$ conda activate envGraphTool
$ conda install -c conda-forge graph-tool
```

And a test if everything worked:

```
(envGraphTool) [user@f33 Downloads]$ which python
/opt/anaconda3/envs/envGraphTool/bin/python
(envGraphTool) [user@f33 Downloads]$ python -V
Python 3.7.9
(envGraphTool) [user@f33 Downloads]$ python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 12:42:55) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import graph_tool as gt
>>> exit()
(envGraphTool) [user@f33 Downloads]$
```