# force home-brew to install graph-tools to the anaconda python interpretor

Tags: python, homebrew, anaconda, graph-tool

Im trying to install graph-tool library on mac os x 10.11.2 machine.
I have two python interpreter installed,  pre-installed python 2.7 and anaconda 3.5

```
$ which python 
/Users/Phoenix/anaconda/bin/python
```

to install graph-tool I had to use home-brew, since this is the recommended method to install graph-tool on mac os.

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install graph-tool
```

the problem I faced that the home-brew is pointing to python 2.7 which is not default python in my case. how I can force home-brew to install this package to the anaconda python?

Comment: You cannot really mix homebrew with anaconda without defeating the whole purpose of isolated environments. I would try to find a way to install graph-tools directly into your anaconda environment. It seems that there are packages on anaconda cloud. But I am not sure how easy it is to install those.

Comment: thanks for ur reply,  I could find that I can install the package by using 
   " conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier graph-tool "
 but the problem that it dint work because, "Could not find some dependencies for graph-tool: cairomm, sigcpp" while both of those libraries are installed already by using brew :/

Comment: and I found vey similar question to mine here, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225291/anaconda-python-how-to-install-missing-dependency
but again the answer their doesn't solve the problem

Comment: As I said, conda is isolated from your system. It does not matter that you already installed these dependencies with homebrew. Have you tried `conda install -c vgauthier -c cyclus graph-tool`?

Comment: i tried and got this conflict $ conda install -c vgauthier -c cyclus graph-tool
Fetching package metadata: ............
Solving package specifications: .........................
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
  - graph-tool
  - python 3.5*

Comment: Well, seems not to be ported to `python3.5`, then. You'd have to use a python3.4 environment for that.

Comment: yea, thanks again :)

Comment: its working :D, thanks a lot but could u plz tell me what -c vgauthier -c cycles mean ?

Comment: It adds additional channels to look for packages, see: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/conda-install.html

Comment: Anyone managed to install graph-tool for anaconda with 2.7 python??

Comment: I created a python3.4 environment, installed sigcpp, then ran conda install -c vgauthier -c cyclus graph-tool which succesfully installed, but it did not fix: the error upon import `dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5boost6python7objects23register_dynamic_id_auxENS0_9type_infoEPFNSt3__14pairIPvS2_EES5_E
  Referenced from: /Users/name/lib/anaconda/envs/graphviz/lib/python3.4/site-packages/graph_tool/libgraph_tool_core.so
  Expected in: flat namespace`