# Can no longer import graph-tool after installing anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, graph-tool

I have installed graph-tool on ubuntu for python2.7 which worked. I have subsequently installed Anaconda. When I now try running `from graph_tool.all import *` from within python I receive the message `ImportError: No module named graph_tool.all`. I have then uninstalled graph-tool again and tried reinstalling it but to no avail. I still receive the error `ImportError: No module named graph_tool.all`. Does anybody know what the problem might be here? I have used the pre-compiled `trusty` distribution.

If I run `/usr/bin/python` I can load graph-tool as normal.

I have also found this post ([Anaconda Python: How to install missing dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225291/anaconda-python-how-to-install-missing-dependency)). Will that give me the official graph-tool version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website gives quite detailed instructions on how to compile graph-tool from source so that it works with Anaconda's Python:
https://gist.github.com/v-pravin/949fc18d58a560cf85d2