# Conda install graph-tool failed on win-64

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, graph-tool

I've tried to install graph-tool via anaconda for python 2.7:

`conda install -c kristanarmstrong graph-tool`

I got the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- graph-tool
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Also I have tried:

`conda install -c jithinpr2 graph-tool
conda install graph-tool
conda remove graph-tool`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46674031) hasn't worked as well.
Previously this package hasn't been installed.

Are there any thoughts what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: maybe follow this to install it [link](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd say be a little more cautious about where you source your code. Unless you know/trust the user, it can be risky to blindly install from someone's personal channel.

The `kristanarmstrong` only hosts a Python 3.4 version.  The `jithinpr2` is a Python 2.7 version, but it's also quite old, which could be the issue.  Otherwise, the fact is that **there are no reliable Conda channels that host the `graph-tool` package for `win-64`**. There is [an open thread on the repo](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/issues/327) discussing improving the installation.

I think the only option you really have here is to follow [the Official Installation Instructions](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#windows).  It looks complicated, so [the Docker option](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#installing-using-docker) looks like it could be your quickest path forward if you just need to get it running and don't care so much about a Conda install.

The ideal solution is for someone to build feedstock for the tool on Conda Forge.