# Installing graph-tool library on conda installed python 3.5, Mac OS

Tags: python-3.5, conda, cairo, graph-tool

Precisely the same as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1054111/configure-error-while-installing-graph-tool), which hasn't been resolved.

[image]

Followed the sequential directions [here](https://gist.github.com/dlozeve/ed59bba8bc8cb9b21e2af36cc9766938); all channels added.

Tried:

1. Adding to `.bash_profile` `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH://anaconda/pkgs` accordingly the directory where there is cairomm installed..
2. `./configure -with--CAIROMM_CFLAGS -with--CAIROMM_LIBS`

Can someone kindly make sure at least I have implemented alternate solutions correctly?

And of course I've tried the simplest `conda install graph-tool` after adding channels from `ostrokach-forge` and the like.
Instead of success, I get the following:

`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa, so unpopular post!

For myself and other novices' use in the future ->
(after all, `conda install`-ed python is easier)

Slightly different but same in that certain library is not reached, acc. to this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225291/anaconda-python-how-to-install-missing-dependency):

`conda` needs to be able to find all the dependencies at once.

The `-c` flag only adds that channel for that one command.

`conda install -c vgauthier rwest graph-tool`. But an easier way is to add those channels to your configuration

`conda config --add channels vgauthier --add channels rwest`

And then perform
`conda install graph-tool`

---

But when I used `conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier graph-tool` command, it worked instantly.

Before that, nothing worked. (when I only used the user name `vguathier` or `ostrokach-forge` or else)

If I type `vi .condarc` I see

```
channels:
  - ostrokach-forge
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

And because I remain quite ignorant in using `brew`-installed packages with `conda`-installed python, I started out by following the directions to install all the necessary dependencies using `brew`. (including `pixman`)

Wonder how the command found everything though.. plus python upgraded to 3.6 from 3.5.

God this is how I am left with solving os issues.. i'm not 100 % clear how I made the computer connect the dots.

---

And still, nonetheless, I am still left with how to figure the install with `./configure`. I want to understand the error msg that was returned and how to address it.